# How to avoid a circular dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

I have two files, both of which define a class.

```
project/
    __init__.py
    thing.py
    thinglist.py
```

`thing.py` defines a class `Thing`, which can output lists of other `Thing`s:

```py
# thing.py
from project.thinglist import ThingList
class Thing:
    def make_more_things(self):
        return ThingList(Thing(), Thing())
```

A `ThingList` is a list of `Thing` objects, which extends list with some other functions sprinkled in:

```py
# thinglist.py
from project.thing import Thing
class ThingList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
        assert all([isinstance(t, Thing) for t in self])
    def some_other_method: pass
```

Instantly we have a problem: a circular dependency. `Thing` needs `ThingList` in order to construct `ThingLists`. `ThingList` needs `Thing` in order to verify that it is made of and only of `Thing`s. But Python won't let me import `Thing` into `thinglist.py`.

To get around this, I could put both classes into the same file. But they're both pretty lengthy and for the sake of my own sanity I really don't want to do that. I could also just omit the `isinstance` check, but then I might be getting errors down the line that could easily be solved right now.

How can I avoid this circular dependency without combining the two files?

Comment: Does importing Thing inside of the ThingList class solves this?

Comment: @RonSerruya It.... does? Importing it during \_\_init\_\_ works just fine. Python sure is a strange place - thank you so much! Add an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose of specifying the container data type is to perform tests, you can write a template-like class Container with all the logic (append, type checks) and only subclass it with `Thing` as container type later in `thing.py`.

For example, in `thinglist.py` you would have

```
class Container:

    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'type_ref'):
            raise NotImplementedError("Type should be set in subclass")
        self._data = []

    def append(self, elt):
        if not isinstance(elt, self.type_ref):
            raise TypeError(f'Element should be of type {self.type_ref}')
        self._data.append(elt)

    ... # rest of the logic
```

and in `thing.py`

```
from thinglist import Container

class ThingList(Container):
    type_ref = Thing
```